# Hyper LogLog algorithm in R

Tags: algorithm, r

Is there is any implementation for hyper LogLog algorithm in R?. I found a javascript implementation : 
[LogLog and HyperLogLog algorithms for counting of large cardinalities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990713/loglog-algorithm-for-counting-of-large-cardinalities)

which way is better to implement the algorithm ? for example, converting the javascript implementation would be good? or should I start from scratch.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of an already existing implementation, although that absolutely does not mean that there none. In regard to writing the code yourself, I would not literally translate the code form the javascript code. The style I would choose in R is very different (more apply loops and vectorisation), probably the code will be shorter.

In stead of literally translating the code, I would write down the steps of the algorithm in pseude code, and then implement the R code from that pseudo code. That way you can more easily write a solution in a real R style, and you have a good opportunity to learn exactly how the algorithm works.